# Linking dependencies with yarn lint in Mac OS X and Linux

Tags: reactjs, graphql, yarnpkg, relay

folks, I've spent a lot of time and still have a problem.

I got monorepo with a few projects, don't ask me why, please :-(

```
repo (relay-compiler, graphql schema)
---repo-one (babel6, webpack3, legacy)
------yarn && cd ../repo-two && yarn link && cd ../repo-one yarn link repo-two
---repo-two (babel7, library with shared components for one and three)
---repo-three(babel7,)
------yarn && cd ../repo-two && yarn link && cd ../repo-three && yarn link repo-two
```

At this moment I have a problem with a build on a Linux machine but on the Mac OS X, everything is ok.

```
ERROR in ../repo-two/Models/Model.js
Module build failed: ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "relay"
```

Comment: Ok, the problem has gone after upgrading babel up to 7 in "project-one". That's a painful project with a lot of bad practice. Oh Lord give me strength :-(